# Scraping live updating information using R

Tags: r, screen-scraping, live

I am new to web scraping and been trying to scrape the right-hand side list of UK local authorities and the number of Covid-19 cases.

Here is the website:
https://www.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/f94c3c90da5b4e9f9a0b19484dd4bb14

I have been able to scrape Wikipedia, but I don't have any idea where to start with the above website. Any tip/links would be very helpful and much appreciated!

Comment: You can download it by clicking provided-download link "Access historic data from the dashboard (xlsx)"

Comment: Thank you. But the only issue with downloading data is that it won't update automatically. Is there any way to scrape the information instead? @nurandi

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to get some numbers in the page with the following code :

```
library(rvest)
library(RSelenium)

port <- as.integer(4444L + rpois(lambda = 1000, 1))
rd <- rsDriver(chromever = "105.0.5195.52", browser = "chrome", port = port)
remDr <- rd$client
remDr$open()

url <- "https://coronavirus.data.gov.uk/"
remDr$navigate(url)
html_Content <- remDr$getPageSource()[[1]]
text <- read_html(html_Content) %>% html_text2()
text <- strsplit(text, "\n")[[1]]

text[54 : 72]
 [1] "Last 7 days – first dose"                                                                            
 [2] "10,536Number of people vaccinated (first dose) in the 7 days to 2 October 2022"                      
 [3] "Total – first dose"                                                                                  
 [4] "45,275,970Total number of people vaccinated (first dose) reported on 2 October 2022"                 
 [5] "Last 7 days – second dose"                                                                           
 [6] "18,800Number of people vaccinated (second dose) in the 7 days to 2 October 2022"                     
 [7] "Total – second dose"                                                                                 
 [8] "42,718,917Total number of people vaccinated (second dose) reported on 2 October 2022"                
 [9] "Last 7 days – booster or third dose"                                                                 
[10] "25,518Number of people vaccinated (booster or third dose) in the 7 days to 2 October 2022"           
[11] "Total – booster or third dose"                                                                       
[12] "33,613,297Total number of people vaccinated (booster or third dose) reported on 2 October 2022"      
[13] "Percentage of population aged 12+"                                                                   
[14] "93.6%Percentage of population aged 12+ vaccinated (first dose) reported on 2 October 2022"           
[15] "First dose"                                                                                          
[16] "88.3%Percentage of population aged 12+ vaccinated (second dose) reported on 2 October 2022"          
[17] "Second dose"                                                                                         
[18] "69.5%Percentage of population aged 12+ vaccinated (booster or third dose) reported on 2 October 2022"
[19] "Booster or third dose"
```

I hope this is helpful!